# Unable to understand the error: Failed to find ".............\.pdf" , perhaps it has been deleted

Tags: pdftex

I have installed TexStudio as well as MikTeX in windows 10. I have written a basic LaTeX script and compiled it. Even though, I did nt get any errors, I am encountering an error, stated as below:

> "Failed to find "..............pdf" , perhaps it has been deleted"

I have already installed all the packages in the MikTex Package Manager.

Would be really glad,if someone can help me regarding this.

## EDIT:

I have written the below script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A Small \LaTeX{} Article Template\thanks{To your mother}}
\author{Your Name  \\
    Your Company / University  \\
    \and 
    The Other Dude \\
    His Company / University \\
    }

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

It compiled.
But, when I was trying to view the PDF, I was getting the error

> "Failed to find file G:\Entertrainment\FullPaper.pdf; perhaps,it has
>   been deleted'

Comment: somewhere in document you call a pdf file, which apparently is not presented where latex looked for it. welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 6):

The problem with your code is that you have no text to be print between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.  To print the title of the article you need to add command `\maketitle`.

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A Small \LaTeX{} Article Template\thanks{To your mother}}
\author{Your Name  \\
    Your Company / University  \\
    \and 
    The Other Dude \\
    His Company / University \\
    }

\begin{document}
\maketitle % <==========================================================
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solution did not help me- I am sure it helped OP since their document compiled (and empty documents indeed don't build) but mine didn't compile *nor* build so I am adding this for other people who Google sends this way.

My problem was actually due to an improper TexStudio <> TexLive setup. So is you have this problem, check if you can run commands: in TexStudio, go to Tools > Commands > Latex.

If you find that the running of commands fails, you know that TexStudio can't really find the binaries such as latex.exe or xelatex.exe.

You can check via Options > Preferences, but instead of searching and entering every binary file, you should add your tex installation to the PATH. In my case, it was TexLive but this applies to MikTex as well.

Relevant links: editing the locations of binaries by hand: [Error: "Make sure that you have installed a (La)TeX distribution"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246316/error-make-sure-that-you-have-installed-a-latex-distribution)

Editing PATH variable: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Info on what needs to be added to PATH- in this case, texLive: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html From the website:

> After the installation finishes, you must add the directory of TeX
> Live binaries to your PATH—except on Windows, where the installer
> takes care of this. For example:
> PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH Use the syntax for
> your shell, your installation directory, and your binary platform name
> instead of x86_64-linux.