# TeXstudio won't compile after I save

Tags: compiling, texstudio, compilation-error, rendering

Apologies in advance for the lack of technical terminology; I'm not so good with computers.

I just started using TeXstudio today, and I'm not entirely sure what happened but now pressing the double green arrow at the top (the one that makes the pdf pop up on the right) I get an error message saying that it failed to find the document.pdf file and that perhaps it has been deleted. I don't understand this, because I thought the double green arrow button created the pdf. The one way I can get it to work is if I start a new document and paste the tex file into the left side (where the code goes), and then hit the double green arrow there to get the pdf. But, once I save the tex file, the same issue comes up again where I can't get it to turn into a pdf on the right side.

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you save the TeX file? (is it in a writable location?)

Comment: Might be duplicate of [pdftex - Unable to understand the error: Failed to find ".............\.pdf" , perhaps it has been deleted - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397096/unable-to-understand-the-error-failed-to-find-pdf-perhaps-it) but maybe not the case. Try both answers there.

Comment: Alternatively there might be something weird e.g. you have some executable named pdflatex in the target. Can't tell for sure without access to your computer