# MiKTeX is not running LaTeX files when writing a basic document

Tags: errors, miktex

When I write:

```
\documentclass {article}
\begin{document}
    some text
\end{document}
```

This error appears:

> Error: One command expansion invalid.
> Parent Command: compile
> Primary Command: quick
>
> Make sure that you have installed a (La)TeX distribution e.g. MiKTeX
> or TeX Live, and have set the correct paths to this distribution on
> the command configuration page. A (La)TeX editor like TeXstudio cannot
> work without the (La)TeX commands provided by such a distribution.

I installed the MiKTeX Console and updated.

[image]

Comment: See this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246316/error-make-sure-that-you-have-installed-a-latex-distribution

Comment: I used the same steps and it didn't solve the problem